# Generic method to convert string to enum type

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

I need to take user input and assert that the value is a valid enum value.  For example, I have an enum:

```
enum Gender {
  Male = 'MALE',
  Female = 'FEMALE',
  Neutral = 'NEUTRAL'
}
```

The user could input any value there and I'd like to assert that the value is a `Gender` if the value is a valid `Gender`.

It'd be handy to have a function like this:

```
function toEnum<T, E extends typeof T>(enumType: E, value: string): T | null {
  if (Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
    return value as T;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Which I could call like this:

```
const a: Gender = toEnum(Gender, 'FEMALE'); // === Gender.Female
const b: Gender = toEnum(Gender, 'APPLE'); // null;
```

I don't really know what generic signature would make the most sense:

```
function toEnum<T, E extends typeof T>(enumType: E, value: string): T | null { /* ... */ }

function toEnum<T>(enumType: typeof T, value: string): T | null { /* ... */ }

function toEnum<E, T instanceof E>(enumType: E, value: string): T | null { /* ... */ }
```

I know those things aren't valid.  I'm just trying to express my intent.

In any case, what's the least hacky way to get typescript to infer that type T will be an enum value while still maintaining type safety?  Is there a better way to write a type safe reverse mapping function for string enums?

EDIT:

Some additional examples to demonstrate what I think I'd like to achieve.  I'd like to infer type `T` so that I can eliminate the strange behaviors and I'd like to avoid using `any` so that I can maintain type safety.

```
enum Gender {
  Male = 'MALE',
  Female = 'FEMALE',
  Neutral = 'NEUTRAL'
}

type Maybe<T> = T | null;

export function toEnum<T>(enumType: any, value: string): Maybe<T> {
  if (Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
    return value as unknown as T;
  }

  return null;
}

const shouldBeFemale: Maybe<Gender> = toEnum<Gender>(Gender, 'FEMALE'); // Gender.Female
const shouldBeNull: Maybe<Gender> = toEnum<Gender>(Gender, 'NOT VALID'); // null

// but this is lame
enum Fruit {
  Apple = 'APPLE',
  Orange = 'ORANGE'
}

const wtfItIsApple: Maybe<Gender> = toEnum<Gender>(Fruit, 'APPLE'); // 'APPLE' . . . wat!?
const validButStillSilly: Maybe<Gender> = toEnum<Gender>(Fruit, 'NOT VALID'); // null
const ughAny: Maybe<Gender> = toEnum<Gender>(217, ':('); // null
```

Comment: This may be lame, but when ever, I require user input converted to ENUM, I follow something like this: `Gender[<any>inputData.gender.toUpperCase()]`. If there is an ENUM available, then ENUM is returned or else NULL is returned. Let me know if this helps (or not)

Comment: @SagarCh, that actually returns a string for me.

Comment: Yeah. Misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type IsEnumKey<T, E> = [E] extends [keyof T] ? true : false;
function toEnum<T, E extends (string | keyof T)>(enumType: T, value: E): IsEnumKey<T, E> extends true ? E : E | null {
  if (Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
    return value as any;
  }

  return null as any;
}

enum Fruit {
    APPLE = "APPLE",
    ORGANE = "ORANGE",
}

const testType = toEnum(Fruit, "APPLE") // Not or null just "Apple";
const testType1 = toEnum(Fruit, "") // "" | null
```

Let me know if this does it for you, conditional return types like this come at the cost of having to cast in the method body (probably avoid casting any or use type-guards though) but gain additional control over the return type.

Known enum members will not return null as a possible return type, however if you want that to happen just change the return type

Unknown enum members will return their type union null.

EDIT: Does this solve it?

```
function toEnum<T, E extends (string | keyof T)>(enumType: T, value: E): [E] extends [keyof T] ? T[E] : E | null {
  if (Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
    return value as any;
  }

  return null as any;
}

enum Fruit {
    APPLE = "APPLE",
    ORGANE = "ORANGE",
}

const testType = toEnum(Fruit, "APPLE") // works;
const testType1 = toEnum(Fruit, "") // "" | null
const testType2: Fruit.APPLE = toEnum(Fruit, "APPLE") // works
```

Final edit: 
You can get around casting in the body of the function with overloading instead of conditional return types, below is a modified nicer solution in which direct casting is no longer required in the method body.

```
function toEnum<T, E extends keyof T>(enumType: T, value: E): T[E];
function toEnum<T, E extends string>(enumType: T, value: E): E | null;
function toEnum<T, E extends string>(enumType: T, value: E): E | null {
  if (Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
    return value as E;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I changed it a little to `const testType: Fruit = toEnum(Fruit, "APPLE")` and I get this: `Type '"APPLE"' is not assignable to type 'Fruit | null'.`  Specifically, I'm looking for this function to return the value cast as the enum type.  I'll update my question to be a little more clear.

Comment: Oh i almost forgot its impossible to map a key in an enum to it's string type, this only works when the keys and the strings are identical.

IE Key APPLE string APPLE

Comment: Hey wait a minute!!  Does typescript infer generic return types!?

Comment: I think it does . . . that's pretty neat . . . so this technically achieves returning the correct return type: `function toEnum<T, E>(enumType: T, value: string): Maybe<E>` . In fact, so does this: `function toEnum<E>(enumType: any, value: string): Maybe<E>`.  I'm not getting type checking on the enumType parameter.  And I'm only safe returning E on the presumption that the enumType is technically `typeof E`.  In any case, my keys and strings don't match.  There may just not be a generic constraint that allows me to say, "`type T` is a `typeof E`."  Or whichever.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to report that the edit did not solve it for me . . . `Type '""' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<Fruit>'.` for `const testType1: Fruit = toEnum(Fruit, "")`.

Comment: That's correct because "" is Fruit | Null so you can't assign it to something that's Fruit. Also yes typescript can infer generic return types in alot of scenarios

Comment: Oops.  Copied the wrong output: `const testType1: Maybe<Fruit> = toEnum(Fruit, "") // "" | null` . I think the problem is in the type inference.  A clearer example is when I change the case of the keys: ```Type '"APPLE"' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<Fruit>'.

const testType: Maybe<Fruit> = toEnum(Fruit, "APPLE") // works;```